# How to get Excel cell fill pattern using c#?

Tags: c#, format, excel-interop

Within an Excel file, how do I go about retrieving a cell's fill pattern? Based on whether a cell has a fill pattern, I want to populate data. Below is what I have tried so far, but "xlPatternNone" is always returned no matter what the cell looks like. Thanks.

```
Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Sheets[sheetName];
        Excel.Range cell = (Excel.Range)workSheet.Range[column + row.ToString()];
        if ((Excel.XlPattern)((Excel.Style)cell.Style).Interior.Pattern == Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternNone)
            cell.Value = value;
```

Info: Excel 2007, c#, Microsoft Interop libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely works:

```
var workSheet = (Worksheet) workBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
var cell = workSheet.Range["A1"];
var style = (XlPattern) cell.Interior.Pattern;
```

I'd therefore suggest that you ignore the `Style` property on the cell and just access the cell's `Interior` directly. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest making sure that `column + row.ToString()` is definitely pointing at the correct cell.

Comment: Worked great, thanks for the help. Any ideas why the style property/object doesn't work?

Comment: No worries. It's because you can apply a "style" containing a number of formatting rules (via "cell styles"), which is distinctly different from a pattern applied directly to the cell.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie : hey, i'm having the same problem when using OpenXml...my problem is : If i have a cell styling applied in my excel, then i'm not able to add the data into the cells..

Comment: Hi @sandy, unfortunately I have no experience with OpenXml, but I've no doubt that if you post your comment as a question, someone will have the answer. Good luck!